# Dependency property or just event

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml

I don't understand this code. What is it?

```
Button.Click => (s,e)
```

and this:

```
(o, args) => ((LocationGridItemControl)o).OnAddress((string)args.NewValue))
```

Comment: please provide the context of your code where you use these events in your code and what confuses you ?

Comment: I got this code Button.Click => (s,e) and question "What is it?". I do not know what it is, so I asked this question.

Comment: it is a lambda expression to invoke the Click even of the button., do you know what events are? if yes then lambda expressions are just a way to express event handlers with some syntactic sugar.

Comment: Okay. I am understand. Thanks